# JSON Diff comparing string with null breaks

Tags: javascript, json, diff

Trying to do JSON diff using: http://tlrobinson.net/projects/javascript-fun/jsondiff

Whenever I have a string value with same key as null value on comparison object it fails with no error...

Left:

```
{
  "mykey": "string value"
}
```

Right:

```
{
    "mykey": null
}
```

If I change the left to anything besides string, it seems to work ok.

```
{
  "mykey": true
}
```

Is this a bug, or some kind of expected behavior? Is there a better tool for what I am trying to do?

Comment: Is this just a bug in that website?

Answer (score 0):

According to my view I think so its something problem with that online tool

There are lots of online tools for checking the difference (JSON, XML,...etc)

Just take a look at this

**http://prettydiff.com/**